# How to store high volume images on cloud?

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, nosql

I need to store a large number of images in the cloud (Amazon EC2). They are already stored on NFS (as a prototype). However, my questions are:

1. Is it better to store them in any db(e.g. NoSQL) or NFS is a good option. (Is it easily scalable?)
2. I need to query these images based on their metadata and make them accessible for users based on query results. Can you compare db and NFS based on accessibility and performance?
3. Is there any appropriate db for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to store your images in [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) if you want to have them accessible in the cloud. Databases either SQL or NoSQL are generally not a common option to store images.

SQL or NoSQL database are generally used to store data or "metadata" so you could store your images (jpg, gif, tiff, bitmap) on Amazon S3 and and your metadata that points to image file in a SQL or NoSQL database. As another option, you could also store your metadata on files in Amazon S3 if all your metadata is in files.

NFS across servers in a share LAN has decent performance but it really depends on how much time and money you want to spend in making your storage system reliable, scalable, etc. (also, if you want to covert it into some sort of object storage mechanism like Amazon S3)  Why reinvent the wheel initially when Amazon S3 provides that for you?  As your data grows you can probably experiment with having your custom storage solution.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I mentioned in my previous comment, in the current version, which is very important scenario, they perform a lot of image processing and computing. This is the reason that they use amazon ec2. I need to add the query functionality to this system. Do you still think S3 is better option or I should combine them?

Comment: In that case you can do the processing in EC2 and then store the final results in S3 for longer term. S3 doesn't have pretty good performance.  If you really need a lot of performance out EC2 you should consider using IO optimized EBS volumes and/or EC2 ephemeral storage.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do exactly this for a job a year ago and we decided to store them in [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and then store their metadata (including the s3 link to the image) in a datastore like [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/%E2%80%8E) (if you won't query on arbitrary metadata) or [SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) (if you want to query on any metadata fields).

The [S3 Bucket size](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/) is theoretically unlimited so you will never run out of space. But by storing the metadata in a faster data store you can write more expressive queries, get better performance and limit the costs of your S3 downloads.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My case is a bit different. First of all, we need to apply vendor independent products. Therefore, DynamoDB or SimpleDB are not good options. This is the reason that I am thinking about using Mongodb. Secondly, the current version is working on Amazon EC2 because of a large amount of image processing and computing which is performed in the system. I need to add query functionality to the system. Under these circumstances, what is your suggestion?